# How to prove $| V | = |A|\operatorname{rank}_A V$, where $V$ is a free $A$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

This question was asked in my assignment on modules and I couldn't solve this particular  question.

> Let $V$ be a free $A$-module of infinite rank. Then $|V | =|A|\cdot\operatorname{rank}_A V= \sup \{ |A|, \operatorname{rank}_A V\}$.

Thoughts: I have been following module theory from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford and this is a masters level course. V is a free A-module implies that there exists an infinite basis  set {$ v_1,..., v_n,... $} . But I don't have any ideas on how will I prove the given result.

Can you please outline a proof?

Comment: Sorry but what is $\vert A \vert $ ? What is $\{ \vert A \vert , Rank_A V\} $?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Cardinality of A

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Are there any issues with the question?

Comment: what is the set inside the sup ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper |A| is cardinality of A and $Rank_A V$ is Rank of V over A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{e_i: i \in I\}$ be a set of basis of $A$. Then every element can be uniquely written as
$$\sum_{j \in J} a_j e_j$$
where $a_j \in A - \{0\}$, and $J$ is a finite subset of $I$.

Fix a finite non-negative integer $n$. We count the number of such elements with $\lvert J \rvert = n$. The number of ways to choose $J$ is
$$\binom{\lvert{I\rvert }}{n} = \lvert{I \rvert}$$
while given $J$, the number of ways to choose $a_j$ is
$$(\lvert{A\vert} - 1)^n.$$
Therefore, the total number of such elements with $\lvert J \rvert = n$ is
$$(\lvert{A\vert} - 1)^n \cdot \lvert{I \rvert} = \lvert{A\rvert} \cdot \lvert{ I\rvert}$$
since $I$ is infinite.

Finally, taking the union over all non-negative $n$, we obtain that the cardinality of $V$ is
$$\lvert{\mathbb{N}\rvert} \cdot \lvert{A\rvert} \cdot \lvert{ I\rvert} = \lvert{A\rvert} \cdot \lvert{ I\rvert}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I am very sorry for having a look and accepting it late.